# How to use Databinding and LiveData for RangeSlider (valueFrom and valueTo)

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-databinding, rangeslider, android-slider

I have the following [RangeSlider](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/slider/RangeSlider) and I am using DataBinding to provide the minimum / maximum value of the slider, as it may change while the user is on the screen.

[image: RangeSlider]

`layout.xml`

```
<layout ...>
    <data>

        <variable
            name="item"
            type="MyDataItem" />
    </data>

    ...

        <com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
            android:id="@+id/my_slider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stepSize="1"
            android:valueFrom="@{item.minimum}"
            android:valueTo="@{item.maximum}"
            ... />
</layout>
```

`MyDataItem`:

```
data class MyDataItem() {
    val minimum = MutableLiveData(Int.MIN_VALUE)
    val maximum = MutableLiveData(Int.MAX_VALUE)
}
```

However, whenever the app tries to inflate the view I get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: valueFrom(0.0) must be smaller than valueTo(0.0)`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete solution how to implement two-way databinding with `RangeSlider`

ViewModel/Presenter:

```
var sliderRange = MutableLiveData<List<Float>>().apply { value = listOf(5f, 90f) }
```

Put there your initial data

Then, layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:valueFrom="1"
    android:valueTo="100"
    app:values="@={vm.sliderRange}" />
```

And finally how to put things together; `BindingAdapter` with `InverseBindingAdapter` :

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "values")
fun getRangeSlider(slider: RangeSlider): List<Float> {
    return slider.values
}

@BindingAdapter("app:valuesAttrChanged")
fun setListeners(
    slider: RangeSlider,
    attrChange: InverseBindingListener
) {
    val listener = RangeSlider.OnChangeListener { _, _, _ -> attrChange.onChange() }
    slider.addOnChangeListener(listener)
}
```

Good luck,'.

Answer (score 0):

The `Int.MIN_VALUE` return a value of 2^-31 so that is smaller than 0.

And `Int.MAX_VALUE` return a value of 2^31 so that is bigger than 100.

`RangeSlider` limits are from 0 to 100. Try to use some values from 0 to 100.

Comment: `RangeSlider`'s max is not limited to 100, as I've successfully set it to the numeric value of `Int.MAX_VALUE` directly in the xml. The issue appears to be with the LiveData, since it's trying to set `valueFrom` to 0 for some reason, despite my LiveData not even being initialized with 0.